# How to identify if an action is performed by a service linked role using cloudtrail logs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

**Objective**:
I am trying to identify if an action logged in cloudtrail logs corresponds to a service linked role.

**What I have tried:**
The first heuristic I used was that it starts with prefix "AWSServiceRoleFor". However this doesn't cover up all the cases.

**Docs I have read:**

1. https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/security/get-greater-transparency-into-actions-aws-services-perform-on-your-behalf-by-using-aws-cloudtrail/: From this document I could infer that userIdentity.sessionContext.sessionIssuer.arn has a 'aws-service-role' in it.
   However I have found cases in my data where that was not the case.
2. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/using-service-linked-roles.html: This suggests that

> "The ARN for a service-linked role includes a service principal, which
> is indicated in the policies below as SERVICE-NAME.amazonaws.com. Do
> not try to guess the service principal, because it is case sensitive
> and the format can vary across AWS services. To view the service
> principal for a service, see its service-linked role documentation."

Again, I found this to be inconsistent as well.

This document contains all the fields present in cloudtrail log: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/cloudtrail-event-reference-record-contents.html

Any insight into which field I could use to identify an action that comes from a service linked role will help.